# Counting # of Times Value Appears in Array In For Loop [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

### **Desired:**

In class *Games*, there is a column named `RoundWinners` that contains arrays filled with multiple `UserId`.  For each *Round* that a player wins, their `UserId` is added to the array:

The front-end displays a list displaying each *Game* in the DB. For each *Game*, I want to count the number of rounds the current user, `currentUserId`, has won, and display this number as `userScore`.

### **Example:**

Current User: *Bob*

#### *Game 1, Score = 2:*

["Bob", "Sue", "Joe", "Bob"]

#### *Game 2, Score = 1:*

["Bob", "Lahkim"]

#### *Game 3, Score = 0:*

["John", "Mark", "Ronnie", "Alice"]

### **Code:**

```
var userScore = 0;
var userScores = [];
    for (i = 0; i < roundWinners.length; i++) {
        if (roundWinners[i] == currentUserId) {
            userScore++;
            userScores.push(userScore);
        };
    };

var numberOf = gameIds.length;              
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    text += "<div class='GameContainer'> + userScores[i] + </div>"; 
    text += "</li>";    

    }
text += "</ul>";

//Ammend HTML
document.getElementById("games").innerHTML = text;
```

### Current Error:

The first game displays a `userScore` of 1, although the current user hasn't won any rounds, and all subsequent games display "undefined".

Comment: And what issues do you have?

Comment: Updated with the current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 2 for loops for this...

```js
var roundWinners = [["Bob", "Sue", "Joe", "Bob"],["Bob", "Lahkim"],["John", "Mark", "Ronnie", "Alice"]];
var gameIds = [1,2,3];
var currentUserId = "Bob";
var userScore;
var userScores = [];
for (i = 0; i < roundWinners.length; i++) {
    userScore = 0;
    for (j=0; j < roundWinners[i].length; j++){
       if (roundWinners[i][j] == currentUserId) {
          userScore++;
       }
    }
    userScores.push(userScore);
}
    
var numberOf = gameIds.length;              
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    text += "<div class='BottomContainer'>" + userScores[i] + "</div>"; 
    text += "</li>";    
    
}
text += "</ul>";
    
//Ammend HTML
document.getElementById("games").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="games"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are always getting 1 as the userScore is because you're pushing the userScore into userScore each time you find a match. Instead, you should loop through all the roundWinners, count the number of times the currentUserId appears, and then push to the array of userScores. I have edited your code below with a comment indicating the change.

```
var userScore = 0;
var userScores = [];
    for (i = 0; i < roundWinners.length; i++) {
        if (roundWinners[i] == currentUserId) {
            userScore++;
        };
    };

//Push to userScores AFTER you finish going through all of the round winners    
userScores.push(userScore);


var numberOf = gameIds.length;              
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    text += "<div class='GameContainer'> + userScores[i] + </div>"; 
    text += "</li>";    

    }
text += "</ul>";

//Ammend HTML
document.getElementById("games").innerHTML = text;
```